# Does Heroku CI support Mongo?

Tags: heroku

I'm a mentor for Thinkful, we've taught hundreds of students to use Heroku along with mLab and Travis CI. With mLab going away, I'm looking at using MongoDB Atlas instead, and now that Heroku CI has launched I'd love to have students consolidate running tests on Heroku CI. However, the tests need to use a Mongo test database, and Travis was able to run mongo for that...wondering if Heroku CI also has the ability to run mongo for the purpose of running tests?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can spin up a Mongo DB instance with one of our partners during testing. You can find more info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci#provisioning-add-ons-the-addons-key